# Use transaction to update value at two different nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two different nodes in database.

- `all posts`
- `users`

As per the fan-out model when a user adds a post , it gets updated at both `all posts` and `users/uid/posts`.

Each post consists of a like button which displays the number of likes.

When a user clicks on it the like should increase by +1.

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions), we use `transaction`for this kind of process.

But the problem with using `transaction` is that it updates only one node *as far as i know*

**But my problem is how shall i update this transaction in both the nodes as mentioned above**

Shall i use `update` method

**What is the way to use transaction that gets updated at both the nodes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push all your logic for updating the database onto the server side with [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).  Use can use a [database trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) to respond to data being written in the database, then execute some JavaScript to make sure the fan-out finishes correctly.  It will have the advantage of making sure all the changes happen without depending on the client.

Transactions can't modify data at two different locations at once, but you will still probably want to use them in your client and Cloud Functions to make sure concurrent writes will not have problems.

Comment: Thank u for your response.... Since i had to use transaction for only the like button in my whole app , what if i do two separate transactions on the like button click to update likes at different nodes? Will it be bad practice?

Comment: Use a transaction *any* time you need an update that's safe in the face of concurrent writes.

Comment: @DougStevenson  same response is valid for Swift? Basically, I am stuck if I am not running any code on a server, right?

Comment: @bibscy That's correct, because all Firebase Realtime Database SDKs have essentially the same capabilities and limitations.

Comment: @DougStevenson  I am trying to perform a multi-path update using the REST API, but I get Bad Request response. Could you please have a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100421 . Thank you