# How to use multi-path update with the REST API in Firebase? Error 400

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vapor

I would like to update multiple nodes in a single operation using the firebase REST API and Vapor framework. 
When I make `.patch` request to Firebase I get error from Vapor client:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Error 400 Bad Request

Could anyone tell me if `finalDictionary` is initialized correctly before being converted in JSON?

Desired output for Users node:

```
 brv-61e24
 Users
  usersUID
    customer
      bookingNumber
       timeStampBookingCancelled
            CleanersUID:"cleanersUID"
            TimeStampBookingClaimed: "TimeStampBookingClaimed"
            TimeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner: "TimeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner"

Cleaners
 cleanersUID
   bookingNumber
     timeStampBookingCancelled
         TimeStampBookingClaimed:"TimeStampBookingClaimed"
         TimeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner: "TimeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner"

Cleaners
 cleanersUID
   bookingNumber
      Claimed: "ClaimedValue"



var finalJSON:JSON?
func makeFinalDictionary() throws -> JSON? {
    let customer = userStripeIdCustomer
    var finalDictionary = Node([:])

    //create base paths
let path0 = "Users/\(usersUID!)/\(customer!)/\(bookingNumber!)/timeStampBookingCancelled"
let path1 = "Cleaners/\(cleanersUID!)/\(bookingNumber!)/timeStampBookingCancelled"
let path2 = "Cleaners/\(cleanersUID!)/\(bookingNumber!)"

    //create final paths and assign values to keys
   finalDictionary[path0] = try Node(node: ["CleanersUID": cleanersUID])
   finalDictionary[path0] = try Node(node:["TimeStampBookingClaimed":timeStampBookingClaimed])
   finalDictionary[path0] = try Node(node:["TimeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner":timeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner])

finalDictionary[path1] = try Node(node:["TimeStampBookingClaimed":timeStampBookingClaimed])
finalDictionary[path1] = try Node(node:["TimeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner":timeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner])

finalDictionary[path2] = try Node(node:["Claimed":claimedValue])

    do {
        finalJSON = try JSON(Node(node:finalDictionary))
    } catch let error as NSError {
        let message = error.localizedDescription
        drop.log.error(message)
        throw NSError(domain: "errorFirebase", code: error.code, userInfo: ["error" : message])
    }
       return finalJSON
}


func writeAsMultiPath(tokenReceived:String!, jsonObject:JSON?) throws -> Void {
    let responseFirebase:Response?
    do{ 
        let token = tokenReceived ?? "defaultValue"
    let response = try drop.client.patch(
            "https://brv-61e24.firebaseio.com.json/", headers: ["Authorization":"Bearer \(tokenReceived)"], query: [:],
            body: jsonObject!)

        responseFirebase = response
    }catch let error as NSError {
        guard let phrase = error.userInfo["error"] as? String else {
            throw NSError(domain: "errorFirebase", code: error.code, userInfo: ["error" : error.localizedDescription])
        }
 throw NSError(domain: "errorFirebase", code: error.code, userInfo: ["error" : phrase])
}
    let body = responseFirebase?.body.bytes
    do {
        jsonFromWritingUsers = try JSON(bytes:body!)
    } catch let error as NSError{
        let message = "jsonFromWritingUsers cannot be converted in JSON line 408 in\(fileName)"
        drop.log.error(message)
        throw NSError(domain: "errorFirebase", code: error.code, userInfo: ["error" : message])
}

        guard responseFirebase?.status.statusCode == 200 else{
          let message1 = "write as multi-path failed line 410 in\(fileName)"
            drop.log.error(message1)
            let message = "fail"
            throw NSError(domain: "errorFirebase", code: 400, userInfo: ["error" : message])
        }     
 }
```

Comment: Idk the syntax of Swift or the Firebase library in iOS but why not try sending those requests to the Firebase cloud functions and then have the cloud server deal with storing the data simultaneously there? Just send the request with the data from the client, don't try to process transactions on the client.

Comment: @DavidVelasquez  I would have to write those functions in JS and I only know swift. So, I spin-up a Vapor server which enables me to use Swift and I make calls using the Firebase REST API. I can write to a single path, but I can;t write to multiple paths in one go, I don't know why. Hopefully someone from Firebase will give some insight.

Comment: I"m not sure if you can write multiple paths in one call. Why not have those paths already created, and then just have some sort of map to map to those fields in Firebase?

Comment: @DavidVelasquez It is possible to write to multiple paths in one call. [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data), [example](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html)

Comment: Maybe you mistakenly wrote this path: "https://brv-61e24.firebaseio.com.json/". think it should be "https://brv-61e24.firebaseio.com/.json".

Comment: @mownier thank you so much. that was the mistake I was making

Comment: @mownier I am coming back to you with another question, this time I am using the Firebase IOS SDK. Many thanks 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797141/